# spring-Unnamed bean definition specifies neither 'class' nor 'parent' nor 'factory-bean' - can't generate bean name

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I met a problem below

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unnamed bean definition specifies neither 'class' nor 'parent' nor 'factory-bean' - can't generate bean name
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/sample-servlet.xml]
```

sample-servlet.xml code
,i don't know how to fix it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.controller"/>

    <bean p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/"
          p:suffix=".jsp"/>

</beans>
```

is there someone who can help me? Thanks  a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bean definition

```
<bean p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/"
      p:suffix=".jsp"/>
```

doesn't declare a `class` attribute which is mandatory in this case. It should be

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:viewClass="some view class"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/"
      p:suffix=".jsp"/>
```

The `p:viewClass` attribute is referring to the property named `viewClass` in the `InternalResourceViewResolver` class. Obviously, set an appropriate value, maybe `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView` or `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView`.

This and more are explained in the [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-definition).